# Intuition behind spectra of products of reflections

Tags: quantum-computation, quantum-information, spectra, projection

I was reading this article by Szegedy [Quantum Speed-Up of Markov Chain based Algorithms](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=1366222), and understand the calculations. Yet I am missing an intuition about why the reflection about the column-space of the factorized matrices $A$ and $B$, with $M = A^*B$ lead to the singular values of $M$.
More concretely, given the discriminant matrix $M$ and the above factorisation, one can perform reflections $\operatorname{ref}_A=2AA^*−I$ and $\operatorname{ref}_B=2BB^*−I$ (where $A^*A=B^∗B=I$), such that the operator $W=\operatorname{ref}_A\operatorname{ref}_B$ has eigenvalues that give the singular values of $M.$

It is clear to me that we obtain (at most) a two dimensional subspace (if we apply those to the corresponding right singular value) and hence obtain invariant subspaces, but I'd like to understand it more intuitively.

Here is [another](https://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~szegedy/PUBLICATIONS/walk_focs.pdf) link for the file.

Comment: Unfortunately, the IEEE link you give is only accessible when your library is affiliated to IEEE... No other site were we can reach, say, an equivalent paper ?

Comment: @JeanMarie, I added the link above, yes! I think this one is public available

Comment: No, it isn't...

Comment: @JeanMarie I put it below the question, sorry! Here it is as well:
https://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~szegedy/PUBLICATIONS/walk_focs.pdf